# Send qq mail in Dart

Tags: dart

I am using [mailer](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/mailer) package to send mail whose host is `QQ` which is very popular in China.

```
String username = 'xx@qq.com';
String password = 'xx';

final smtpServer = new SmtpServer("smtp.qq.com", port: 465, username: username, password: password);

// Create our message.
final message = new Message()
  ..from = new Address(username, 'Your name')
  ..recipients.add('receiver@qq.com')
  ..subject = 'Test Dart Mailer library ::  :: ${new DateTime.now()}'
  ..text = 'This is the plain text.\nThis is line 2 of the text part.'
  ..html = "<h1>Test</h1>\n<p>Hey! Here's some HTML content</p>";

final sendReports = await send(message, smtpServer);
```

However it fails. Is there anything I left?

Comment: "However it fails." does mean what exactly?

Comment: It means it does not send an email.

Comment: https://github.com/kaisellgren/mailer/issues/71

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The qq smtp server requires the ssl flag:

```dart
String username = 'xx@qq.com';
String password = 'xx';

final smtpServer = new SmtpServer("smtp.qq.com", ssl: true, port: 465, username: username, password: password);
```

(Note the `ssl: true` argument).

In addition version 2.2.0 now has a `qq(username, password)` SMTP server definition function (similar to the `gmail` function).